# How can I make projectiles shoot in a circle?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a variable amount of projectiles shoot in a circle flying all at the same speed but at different angles. I'm using python, specifically CMU CS Academy if that helps. How can I make this work? this is what i have so far:

```
for i in range(int(amount)):
        x,y=getPointInDir(shape.centerX,shape.centerY,(i*(360/(amount))),20)
        ray=Line(shape.centerX,shape.centerY,x,y,fill='yellow')
        raytracer=Circle(ray.x2,ray.y2,1,fill='black')
        raytracer.dx=ray.centerX/360
        raytracer.dy=ray.centerY/360
        raytracers.add(raytracer)
```

and

```
def onStep():
    for raytracer in raytracers:  
        raytracer.centerX+=raytracer.dx
        raytracer.centerY+=raytracer.dy
```

I've tried to set the dx and dy from the centerX of the origin but instead of providing a circle it shoots in the shape of a square

Comment: Cosine and sine are your friend